# Input-Tag Feature-Detection in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Could somebody explain exactly how this feature detection is working?

```
// Create a dummy element for feature detection
if (!('placeholder' in $('<input>')[0])) {
```

This line of code detects whether or not the browser supports the placeholder attribute on input elements.

I'd like to be a bit more comfortable with what is going on under the hood here before deploying to production.

Will this end up cycling through all possible attributes of the input element, just to check for the existence of a `placeholder` element? If this is the case, I was not aware that we get access (in some fashion) to elements that aren't spelled out explicitly in the markup.

[Code Source](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/form-placeholder-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to any element created with javascript, regardless of whether or not that element is appended to the page itself or not. So if you create an element, you can change it, like so:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');
    element.style.border = '1px solid red';
    element.value = 'some value';
```

Now to create an element in jQuery you do:

```
$('<input />')
```

and of course the `[0]` at the end gets the native DOM element, so these two are exactly the same:

```
var DOM_element1 = $('<input />')[0];
var DOM_element2 = document.createElement('input');
```

Once you have created an element, all properties of that element are available as well, such as `element.value` etc.

If the browser supports placeholders, the placeholder attribute will be present on an input element, and since the element we created is in fact a node or element object, we use the `in` keyword to check if that property is available:

```
var element = document.createElement('input');

if ('placeholder' in element) {
    //the element has a placeholder attribute, 
    //so it must be supported by the browser
}
```

another way to do the same thing would be to check the property directly to see that it's not undefined, like so:

```
if (typeof element.placeholder!=undefined) {  //should return string if present

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not an attribute for an element is supported by the browser basically boils down to whether the browser's javascript environment has a definition for that attribute for that element.

If the definition exists, a 'get' access of the attribute should return a non-null value for that attribute, whereas if the definition does not exist a null/'falseish' (i.e. something that javascript interprets as false) value is returned.

The code in question exploits javascript's 'truish'/'falseish' interpretations of values, to use the return value of a 'get' access on the attribute as a predicate for feature detection.